# Adding external from parallel project directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Trying to add externals to my project. Directory structure is following:

```
`c:\projects\Project1\` - contains main project
`c:\projects\Project2\externalToProject1\` - contains external to main project
```

I'm adding external by setting path to `..\Project2\externalToProject1\` in `Project1`. Instead of that I got updeted `Project1` with directory `..Project2externalToProject1` in it.

How to solve problem with external?

I'm using `Turtoise` `SVN` client for `Windows`.

P.S. Why I need external
Project `c:\projects\Project2\externalToProject1\` is set of .cpp and .h files that I use in several projects. I would like to keep this set up to date in all projects since this library set contains serialization rules and projects do communication between each other by using it.

```
UPD:
svn.exe pg svn:externals -R -v c:\projects\project2
gives nothing

svn.exe pg svn:externals -R -v c:\projects\project1
gives:
svn:externals
    http://GMW8:85/svn/Project2/externalToProject1 ..\Project2\externalToProject1\
```

Comment: Clearly you are applying something wrong here. Best method to solve your problem is to show screenshot with your data or the commands you applying. Also state a little bit clearer what you want to have in the end.. seems fine to me what you got.

Comment: I want to see the output of 

svn propget svn:externals -R c:\projects\project2

that and maybe chat a bit about why you want to use externals - I believe it's almost always not the best plan.

Comment: I have updated my question body with command output

Answer (score 1):

> Directory structure is following

Directory structure is (almost) irrelevant here.

You **must**:

- Read carefully and understand `svn help ps` in part of `svn:externals` definition
- See difference between absolute and relative URL in externals
- Having knowledge about repository's URLs for externals source and target, build correct definition

`c:\projects\Project1\` and `c:\projects\Project2\externalToProject1\` mean **nothing** - they are local paths of Working Copies, while you must operate with **REPOSITORIES URLs**

Yes, show `svn pg svn:externals -R -v c:\projects\project2`, if you want to get good&full answer